# jQuery JSON Parse - Unexpected Token Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm trying to use Envato API to gather some user stats w/ jQuery. I'll show an example response JSON:

```
{
"new-files-from-user":[
    {
    "thumbnail":"http://3.s3.envato.com/files/60560.jpg",
    "tags":"",
    "user":"collis",
    "url":"http://themeforest.net/item/manilla-photoshop-design/22803",
    "live_preview_url":"http://2.s3.envato.com/files/60561/1_Home.__large_preview.jpg",
    "uploaded_on":"Wed Dec 03 03:32:35 +1100 2008",
    "cost":"10.00",
    "item":"Manilla Photoshop Design",
    "sales":"294",
    "rating":"4",
    "id":"22803"
    },
    {
    "thumbnail":"http://2.s3.envato.com/files/60223.jpg",
    "tags":"clean",
    "user":"collis",
    "url":"http://themeforest.net/item/black-white-simple-theme/22705",
    "live_preview_url":"http://0.s3.envato.com/files/60224/1_home.__large_preview.jpg",
    "uploaded_on":"Tue Dec 02 04:01:12 +1100 2008",
    "cost":"8.00","item":"Black + White Simple Theme",
    "sales":"272","
    rating":"4",
    "id":"22705"
    },
    {
    "thumbnail":"http://1.s3.envato.com/files/44556.jpg",
    "tags":"clean",
    "user":"collis",
    "url":"http://themeforest.net/item/quik-v1-admin-skin/17314",
    "live_preview_url":"http://3.s3.envato.com/files/44557/1_green.__large_preview.jpg",
    "uploaded_on":"Fri Sep 05 07:30:24 +1000 2008","cost":"12.00",
    "item":"Quik v1 Admin Skin",
    "sales":"336",
    "rating":"5",
    "id":"17314"
    },
    {"thumbnail":"http://3.s3.envato.com/files/45212.jpg",
    "tags":"clean",
    "user":"collis",
    "url":"http://themeforest.net/item/freshcorp-business-template/17528",
    "live_preview_url":"http://3.s3.envato.com/files/45213/1_Homepage.__large_preview.jpg",
    "uploaded_on":"Tue Sep 09 06:10:50 +1000 2008",
    "cost":"20.00",
    "item":"FreshCorp - Business Template",
    "sales":"277",
    "rating":"4","id":"17528"
    },
    {"thumbnail":"http://0.s3.envato.com/files/45739.jpg",
    "tags":"clean",
    "user":"collis",
    "url":"http://themeforest.net/item/real-estate-html-template/17732",
    "live_preview_url":"http://0.s3.envato.com/files/45740/1_homepage.__large_preview.jpg",
    "uploaded_on":"Fri Sep 12 14:22:45 +1000 2008",
    "cost":"20.00","item":"Real Estate HTML Template",
    "sales":"175",
    "rating":"4",
    "id":"17732"
    }
]
}
```

Here's my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//this gets JSON data from an url
$.getJSON("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/new-files-from-user:collins,themeforest.json?callback=?",
//this function gets called when data has been recieved
function(data){
    //parsing JSON data, line by line(like foreach)
    $.each(data['new-items-from-user'], function(i,item){
        //puts all titles in our div
        $("#test").append(item.item+"<br />");
    });
});
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

And here's what I get in the Chrome console: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token :' (pic http://imgur.com/8qoqO).

I'm not sure if I have an error in my code that's causing this problem, but here's a fiddle to see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/wkmDj/

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: the `:` in the url causes the error, either because jQuery parses it and doesn't like it or the XHR object itself doesn't like it.

Comment: Is there a workaround for that? Do you think URL encoding would solve it?

Comment: Edit: on the Chrome console it says it's getting the error from the JSON feed, I'll update my post with a pic

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant either: my safari client complains that the resource is being sent with MIME type application/octet-stream. That doesn't sound right, does it?

Comment: I think that the question mark at the end of your URL is one problem. The error message changes if you drop it.

Comment: -Summers, the 'octet-stream' is part of a .htaccess modification that makes sure that your computer downloads the JSON feed instead of viewing it in your browser. 

-Seth, the question mark is necessary (part of callback) so that the JSON can be accessed by jQuery, otherwise you get 'Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.'

Comment: Try urlencoding the colon and the very last question mark, see if that works.

Comment: Guys, it loads the JSON fine, it's the colon *inside* the JSON response that's causing the problem http://jsfiddle.net/AWq7D/1/

Comment: @Matt that's because the raw JSON is being interpreted by the JavaScript parser just as it is - there's no callback function.  In other words, the JSONP response is coming back without the function call wrapped around the JSON data.

Answer (score 2):

In the second object in the list in the JSON response, there's a line break in the middle of a property name:

```
"sales":"272","
rating":"4",
"id":"22705"
```

Maybe that's just a transcription error.

*edit* — OK that was a transcription error.  I think the problem is that the website you're talking to doesn't really understand JSONP properly.  It's returning JSON that looks fine, but JSONP requires that the JSON be returned wrapped up in a function call.  In other words, the response should look like:

```
somefunction({"new-items-from-user":[{ ... }]});
```

It's not doing that, so when the JSON is evaluated by itself it constitutes a syntax error because JavaScript thinks that leading `{` is the start of a **code** block, not an object literal.

Looking at the documentation for that API, I see nothing to suggest that it's intended to be used as a JSONP service.  It looks like they intend that it be used from something like a phone app or from a web server or something like that, but not from JavaScript in the browser via JSONP.

Comment: Yep, here's my code http://jsfiddle.net/AWq7D/2/ but I don't know why I'm getting that error.. :/

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the JSON but I'm still trying a couple of things.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem, the code has:

```
data['new-items-from-user']
```

But the data looks like this:

```
{"new-files-from-user":[]}
```

Comment: They work the same way. I updated my fiddle and I'm getting the error when jQuery tries reading the JSON feed http://jsfiddle.net/AWq7D/1/

Comment: Why would that be a problem?  The property name is "new-files-from-user", and in the code that's how it's being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Pointy said, response is not getting parsed as json, but as script. So `eval` function is being executed.

```
eval('{"new-files-from-user":[]}');
```

and it is giving error.

In the case of jsonp if the url is **http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/new-files-from-user:mechabyte,themeforest.json**, call should be made as

```
http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/new-files-from-user:mechabyte,themeforest.json?callback=mycallback
```

and response should be

```
mycallback({"new-files-from-user":[]});
```

and if you have a function `mycallback`

```
eval('mycallback({"new-files-from-user":[]});');
```

will work

or if you don't set a callback

```
http://marketplace.envato.com/api/edge/new-files-from-user:mechabyte,themeforest.json?callback=
```

the response should be

```
({"new-files-from-user":[]});
```

then

```
eval('({"new-files-from-user":[]});');
```

will work

In your case you can see that each time jQuery is setting the parameter `callback` like

```
callback=jQuery171009222313176259944_1327017091413
```

so the response should be

```
jQuery171009222313176259944_1327017091413({"new-files-from-user":[]});
```

e.g: https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/tomhanks.json?callback=myCallback&count=5

But as the response is a json string this will work. (subject to same origin policy)

```
$.get("http://marketplace.envato.com/api/v3/new-files-from-user:turkhitbox,themeforest.json?callback=?",
function (data){
   data = $.parseJSON(data);
   console.log(data);
});
```